# In Tkinter, is it possible to retrieve the list of callback functions bound to a widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback

Given the following code in which multiple callbacks are associated with a single button:

```
import tkinter as tk

def hi(event):
    print('hello')
    return hi

def bye():
    print('bye')
    return bye

def salutations(event):
    print('... and salutations...')
    return bye

def and_so_forth(event):
    print('... and so forth...')
    return bye

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='test', command = bye)
button.bind("<Button-1>", hi)
button.bind("<Button-1>", salutations, "+")
button.bind("<Button-1>", and_so_forth, "+")

button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Is there a method I can call that will list all callbacks bound to `button`?

The results I'd like to get are something akin to:

```
command_list = ('hi', 'salutations', 'and_so_forth', 'bye')
```

What I've tried:

- I searched the property list, but didn't see anything promising.
- button.command.get() (it's ignored)
- button.command.cget() (also ignored)
- button.invoke() (only reports on `bye` function)

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I've found is the `_tclCommands` attribute:

```
commands = button._tclCommands
print(commands)
# >>> ['1310081992192bye', '1310100638592hi', '1310100643904salutations', '1310100643712and_so_forth']
```

Given the leading underscore, I don't imagine you're supposed to do this, but it's as close as I could get. Also, bear in mind that those leading numbers change every time you run your app.

It's a bit cumbersome, but you can also cross-reference this list with the functions listed by `dir()` to get the names of the callbacks for a given widget:

```
def get_callbacks(widget):
    callbacks = []
    for fn in dir():  # list all functions in this module
        for callback_name in widget._tclCommands:  # get callbacks
            if fn in callback_name:  # print matches
                callbacks.append[fn]
    return callbacks

# naturally, this could also be done with a list comprehension, but it's
# a bit easier to see what's going on this way
# callbacks = [fn for fn in dir() for cmd in widget._tclCommands if fn in cmd]
```

---

**EDIT** to point out that if you have a binding to a `lambda` on your widget, then the `_tclCommands` attribute will include something along the lines of `'2160369114752<lambda>'` for each `lambda` bound. In this case, cross-referencing `dir()` won't work, so you'll have to resort to just stripping the numbers off instead.

Comment: Nice! I can strip the first 13 characters off the strings to end up with just the names. 13 characters seems consistent so far. Thanks, JRiggles.

Comment: Happy to help! If this worked out for you, please mark this answer as "accepted" so that others know this question has been answered. Good luck on the project!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. If you were writing this code in Tcl, the answer is "yes". `bind` without giving it a callback (eg: `.button bind <Button-1>`) returns a list of the callbacks associated with the binding. However, tkinter has to add a wrapper around the callback, yielding a result that is hard to understand.

For example, given this code:

```
print(button.bind("<Button-1>"))
```

... in your case it yields something like this:

```
if {"[4346304576hi %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break

if {"[4346304832salutations %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break

if {"[4346305024and_so_forth %# %b %f %h %k %s %t %w %x %y %A %E %K %N %W %T %X %Y %D]" == "break"} break
```

You could try to parse that, but there's no guarantee the result will be the same in future versions of tkinter, and the exact number that you have to strip off will likely be different each time you run.

It might be better off to create your own subclass of `Button` and keep track of your bindings yourself. Off the cuff, it might look something like this:

```
class CustomButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._custom_bindings = []

    def bind(self, sequence=None, func=None, add=None):
        if func is None and add is None:
            return self._custom_bindings
        elif func is not None and add is None:
            self._custom_bindings = [func]
        elif func is not None and add is not None:
            self._custom_bindings.append(func)

        return super().bind(sequence=sequence, func=func, add=add)
```

With that, you can call `button.bind("<Button-1>")` to get a list of the functions.

Comment: I see what you did there, Bryan. Thanks.

Comment: One limitation to this approach is that it only reports those callbacks bound to `"<Button-1>"`. Any callback associated during button instantiation or via `config()` will be missed.